# How many samples are needed to justify a given standard deviation?

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation, sample-size, statistical-power

Context: Someone was asking about individuals with measured IQ above 200. My intuition is that there is not a sufficiently large population of people to justify measurements of scores well past 200.

The assumption is that IQ follows a Gaussian distribution.

I was trying to argue that the normality of the IQ distribution is not plausible past a certain point, so high scores can't be trusted. I put 1/7.737 billion into a calculator of standard deviation for a given percentile and found that it corresponds to a score of about 194.

What I was hoping for was to then be able to state what sample size would be needed to show there is at least some (for some small probability such as 1/1000, because rare events do occur) chance of at least one individual with a IQ of 250 (10 SDs). My intuition is that hundreds of billions of samples would be needed for even a 1/1000 probability.

Is there a closed form formula for the needed sample size to state a given SD measurement  should exist with some set probability?

Comment: Assuming normality, a Ci for $\sigma^2$ (unknown $\mu)$ results from 'pivoting' the relationship
$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1).$ So $n=11, S^2=15$ gives a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ of length about 38.9 and $n=101, S^2 =15$ gives a 95% CI of length about 8.63. In R
`diff(150/qchisq(c(.975,.025),10))` returns $38.87379$ and
`diff(1500/qchisq(c(.975,.025),100))` returns $8.632121.$ // To get CI for SD $\sigma,$ take square roots of endpoints of such CIs.

Comment: For more detail, google `confidence interval for variance`, perhaps see [this page](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/book/export/html/810) that I found in my search.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "make sense."  And, in this context, what *exactly* do you mean by a "given measurement"?

Comment: @whuber There are a little under 8 billion people alive right now. So if someone takes an IQ test that predicts their IQ at 250+, there really are not enough people for that score to be believable. You can't have a measurement 10 standard deviations away from the mean without many more people to sample from. Correct?

Comment: Not necessarily correct, for several reasons.  One is that the normality of the IQ distribution is not plausible that far out in the tails.  Another is that rare events do happen.  What is lacking here is any clear sense of context, definitions, or assumptions.  One possible interpretation is that you might be asking what sample size of a truly Normal distribution would be needed to assure, with a stated probability, that the sample includes a stated number of values a specified number of SDs from the mean--but that's only one of many ways we might try to interpret your question.

Comment: Well. I was trying to argue that the normality of the IQ distribution is not plausible past a certain point, so high scores can'tbetrusted. I put 1/7.737 billion into a calculator of standard deviation for a given percentile and found that it corresponds to a score of about 194. What I was hoping for was to then be able to state what sample size would be needed to show there is at least some (say 1/1000, because rare events do occur) chance of at least one individual with a IQ of 250 (10 SDs). My intuition is that hundreds of billions of samples would be needed for even a 1/1000 probability.

Comment: Thank you: that is becoming more understandable and more specific.  Could you edit your post to include those latest clarifications?

Comment: I thought that the IQ distribution is _defined_ as Gaussian. In that case it makes no sense to question (or doubt) values in the tails. What am I missing?